# How to assign values to checkbuttons and use them to calculate a score?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, logic

I am writing a multiple choice quiuz in Tkinter and have used checkbuttons for some of my questions where the user is to select 'all correct answers'. I have created variables that will store the value of the checkbuttons (on/off values - 1/0). However, the computer doesn't seem to understand the value of the variables and so in the 'calculate score' if statement the computer is unable to make the comparison as it doesn't recognize the value of the checkbuttons.

```
class Question_5_Window(tk.Toplevel):
    '''A simple instruction window'''
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.text = tk.Label(self, width=100, height=4, text = "5) What would you do if you were walking to class and you saw a first year crying? Tick all correct answers.")
        self.text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        question_5_Var1 = IntVar()
        question_5_Var2 = IntVar()
        question_5_Var3 = IntVar()

        A_5 = Checkbutton(self, text = "Keep walking", variable = question_5_Var1, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=5, width = 20)
        A_5.pack()

        B_5 = Checkbutton(self, text = "Take them to guidance", variable = question_5_Var2, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=5, width = 20)
        B_5.pack()

        C_5 = Checkbutton(self, text = "Talk to them to resolve issue", variable = question_5_Var3, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=5, width = 20)
        C_5.pack()

        def calculate_score():

            if (question_5_Var2 == True) and (question_5_Var3 == True):
                print("calculate score has worked")
            else:
                print("not worked")

        Enter_5 = Button(self, text= "Enter", width=10, command = calculate_score)
        Enter_5.pack()

    def flash(self):
        '''make the window visible, and make it flash temporarily'''

        # make sure the window is visible, in case it got hidden
        self.lift()
        self.deiconify()

        # blink the colors
        self.after(100, lambda: self.text.configure(bg="black", fg="white"))
        self.after(500, lambda: self.text.configure(bg="white", fg="black"))
```

Comment: `question_5_Var2` is an `IntVar`, why should it equal `True`? You probably want to check its `value` instead, using `get()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `question_5_VarX` variables are of type `IntVar`, so they will not be `True` in any case. You should check their `value` instead, using the `get()` method. Note that the value will be an `int`, but you can use it just like a boolean.

```
if question_5_Var2.get() and question_5_Var3.get() and not question_5_Var1.get():
```

(You might also want to check that the first answer is *not* checked.)

Comment: Sorry I originally had them as '1' instead of True but changed them to see what would happen.

Comment: @user3056786 The important thing is to use `get()` instead of comparing the variable itself. So, did this work then?